# More clarification about the usage of split in Perl

Tags: arrays, string, csv, while-loop, split

I have this following input file:

**test.csv**

```
done_cfg,,,,
port<0>,clk_in,subcktA,instA,
port<1>,,,,
```

I want to store the elements of each CSV column into an array, but I always get error when I try to fetch those "null" elements in the csv when I run the script. Here's my code:

```
# ... assuming file was correctly opened and stored into
# ... a variable named $map_in

my $counter = 0;

while($map_in){
    chomp;
    @hold_csv = split(',',$_);

    $entry1[$counter] = $hold_csv[0];
    $entry2[$counter] = $hold_csv[1];
    $entry3[$counter] = $hold_csv[2];
    $entry4[$counter] = $hold_csv[3];

    $counter++;
}
print "$entry1[0]\n$entry2[0]\n$entry3[0]\n$entry3[0]"; #test printing
```

I always got `use of uninitialized value` error whenever i fetch empty CSV cells
Can you help me locate the error in my code ('cause I know I have somewhat missed something on my code)?

Thanks.

Comment: **ALLWAYS** `use strict;  use warnings;`

Comment: hi toto

i always do `use strict; use warnings;` at the start of my program. `map_in ` is the container for `test.csv` during the `open` command.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like CSV. So the tool for the job is really `Text::CSV`.

I will also suggest - having 4 different arrays with numbered names says to me that you're probably wanting a multi-dimensional data structure in the first place.

So I'd be doing something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1 } );

open( my $input, "<", "input.csv" ) or die $!;
my @results; 

while ( my $row = $csv->getline($input) ) {
   push ( @results, \@$row );  
}

print join ( ",", @{$results[0]} ),"\n";
print Dumper \@results;
close($input);
```

If you really want separate arrays, I'd suggest naming them something different, but you could do it like this:

```
 push ( @array1, $$row[0] );   #note - double $, because we dereference
```

I will note - there's an error in your code - I doubt:

```
while($map_in){
```

is doing what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

When you're assigning `$entryN`, define a default value:

```
$entry1[$counter] = $hold_csv[0] || '';
```

same for other `@entry`

I think there is a typo in `while($map_in) {` it should be `while (@map_in) {`.